# QGIS Raster resampling without label changes

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, raster-conversion, resampling, qgis-grass-plugin

I am working on raster data that which is in a 5x5 meter resolution. I need to resample this to a 25x25 meter resolution. I have used resample.stats which works, but changes the label numbers into one with decimals.

[image]

Is there a way of resampling the raster into a 25x25 meter resolution without changing the labels? As I need these to be integers to work with the data after reprojection.
The attached picture displays before and after of the data.

Comment: "Reproject" is the wrong term -- "Resample" is correct.  By default, resampling 25 cells into one will result in an *average* of the pixel values. You need to [Edit] the Question to contain the exact command you used in order for someone to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @user2856 that did the trick indeed, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [resampling method](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.resamp.stats.html) from the default average to something that doesn't return a floating point value like min, max or mode.